# Placement of "dont" in this sentence

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

If you were to translate "Do you have an idea that you want us to try?"

Would you translate it as

> Avez-vous une idée dont vous voulez que nous essayions?

Or

> Avez-vous une idée que vous voulez dont nous essayions?

Answer (score 2):

The translation I'm thinking of is :

> Avez-vous une idée **que** vous voulez **que** nous essayions ?
>
> Auriez-vous une idée **que** vous voudriez **que** nous essayions ?

Anyway, your second sentence is incorrect. You can not use **vous voulez dont**, the correct form would be **dont vous voulez** that you used in your first sentence.

You could indeed say :

> Avez-vous une idée **dont vous voulez** la suprématie ?

But in this context it sounds really strange to me :

> Avez-vous une idée **dont vous voulez** que nous essayions ?

The idiomatic way to say it would be my first translation.

Comment: How bout "Do you have a topic that you want us to talk about?", would you translate it as "Avez-vous un sujet donc vous voulez que nous parlions?"

Comment: Almost correct, care about the diffrence between "donc" and "dont".  I would say something like "Avec-vous un sujet dont vous voulez que nous parlions ?" or "Voulez-vous que nous parlions d'un sujet ?"

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo :)

Comment: @Kii Attention, tu as fait une faute de frappe à "Avez-vous".

Comment: @SimonDéchamps : bien vu, c'est vrai.

Answer (score 2):

Both phrases are not correct. If you want to keep this grammatical structure, you should say:

> Avez-vous une idée **que** vous voulez **que** nous essayions?

but it sounds strange to my ears.

A more natural way would be:

> Y a-t-il une idée que vous voulez que nous essayions ?

(the interrogative form of `il y a une idée...`)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I forgot. Essayer de is only for verbs. How bout "Y a-t-il un sujet dont vous voulez que nous parlions dans la prochaine vidéo?"?

Comment: Indeed, "Y a-t-il un sujet dont vous voulez que nous parlions" is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Or… Voudriez-vous essayer l’une de ces/mes idées.

Answer (score 0):

As Kii said, the translation would be :

> Avez-vous une idée que vous voulez que nous essayions ?

If you want to use "dont", then you'd say :

> Avez-vous une idée dont vous voudriez que nous **l'**essayions ?

Comment: Why is a "l'" necessary in this case?

Comment: If you say "Avez-vous une idée dont vous voudriez que nous essayions ?", the sentence is incomplete. We're waiting for something to try in this sentence, for example : "Avez-vous une idée dont vous voudriez que nous essayions le début ?"

The " l' " stands for the idea, because it's weird to say "Avez-vous une idée dont vous voudriez que nous essayions l'idée ?"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand very well. Because I've seen in French that if a word like que is followed by a verb like souhaiter, vouloir, penser, it's generally preceded by a "le" or "l'", is essayer in this case? "Elle n'est pas aussi stupide que Tu le penses", "je reste ici aussi longtemps que vous le souhaitez", "Il l'a fait comme vous l'avez voulu", is this the same case?

Comment: In your examples, the "entire" sentences would be : "Elle n'est pas aussi stupide que tu penses qu'elle l'est" ; "Je reste ici aussi longtemps que vous souhaitez que je reste" ; "Il l'a fait comme vous avez voulu qu'il le fasse". So it's basically the same case : in order not to repeat the last part of the sentences, you replace it by a pronoun. "le" or "l'" do not precede the verbs souhaiter, vouloir, etc. because of these specific verbs, but because they replace a part of the sentence (I'm not sure if I'm being clear :s)

Comment: So "Quel type de nourriture penses-tu que je devrais cuisiner" has to be "Quel type de nourriture penses-tu que je devrais le cuisiner"? Since the le stands for type de nourriture? "Quel type de nourriture penses-tu que je devrais cuisiner le type de nourriture que tu as choisi"? Or "tu l'as choisi"? Oh my this is so confusing

Comment: Well, actually not... You just say "Quel type de nourriture penses-tu que je devrais cuisiner ?". As for why, I guess I have to think about it...... (but I'm pretty sure I made a mistake in my last answer, maybe it's actually because of the verb, and its transitivity)

Comment: _Avez-vous une idée dont vous voudriez que nous **l'**essayions ?_ does not sound right to my ears.  _dont_ is for a complement introduced by _de_, so to have one here you need something like _Avez-vous une idée dont vous voudriez que nous examinions la faisabilité?_ (cfr _vous voulez que nous examinons la faisabilité *de* votre idée_)

Comment: This is a subject that's always confused me haha. It's very strange in English to translate the "entire" sentences.

Comment: Hi, I think this link will help :) http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/directobjects_2.htm

Answer (score -1):

I would say

> Avez-vous une idée de ce que vous voulez que nous essayions.

But in an other way, I would prefer say:

> Pouvez-vous m'indiquer ce que vous souhaiteriez que nous essayions?
>
> Pouvez-vous m'indiquer ce que vous attendez de notre part?

Regards,

Comment: I don't think those are correct... De ce que is supposed to be "ce dont" I think. "Avez vous une idée ce dont" still isn't correct because the noun is already specified. Also it's "Vous souhaiteriez".

Comment: « Pouvez-vous m'indiquer ce que vous attendez de notre part? » is correct.

(forgiving the fact there is a space before '!' or '?' in french…)